# How to read book local swf files folder?

Tags: java, android

I am creating android application for book reader , I have book in **swf** file(folder)
I was try to load **swf** file in WebView but not working , please anyone suggest me.
 thanks

Comment: please consider this faq https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: hi @kling klang  sir  please   help me

Comment: Same problem here  please help me

Comment: As far as I know, **swf** is not natively supported by Android. If you are lucky, you might be able to find some library that could serve the purpose, but this is **your business**.